# Unable to restrict number of records to be fetched to client in firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Query:

```
Query query = mDatabase.child("feeds").child(id).orderByChild("fTime");
query.limitToFirst(20);
```

I am expecting to receive only 20 records, but it actually returns me all the records available. **How do I restrict the fetched record counts?**

My Data structure:

```
feeds : {
    feedId : {
        fName : name1,
        fTime : 123
    }
}
```

My Rules:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null",
        "feeds" : {
            ".indexOn": ["fTime"]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `limitToFirst` returns a new query. Whereas you are expecting it to modify the current reference.

Instead try this:

```
Query query = mDatabase.child("feeds").child(id).orderByChild("fTime");
Query limitQuery = query.limitToFirst(20);
```